# null document and -1 caretOffset in AsyncCompletionQuery.query

Tags: netbeans-platform

Hi I have implemented a new language lexer using JavaCC. It is by no means a great implementation as this is the first time I have written a  JavaCC grammer file. But I have been able to make the syntax highlighting working. I don't have a need to implement a parser so I didn't. But now I want to provide code completion for keywords. Please find implementations of CompletionProvider, CompletionItem and ExampleKeywords classes below. For some reason the `dcmnt` and `caretOffset` in `query` method are being set to `null` and `-1` respectively.

Code completion shows all the keywords, but I am unable to filter the keywords as the user types things in because the Document and the caretOffset are off.

Do I need to implement a parser to be able to use the code completion? Actually any help towards resolving this issue is appreciated.

**ExampleKeywordCompletionProvider**

```
@MimeRegistration(mimeType = "text/x-example", service = CompletionProvider.class)
public class ExampleKeywordCompletionProvider implements CompletionProvider {

    public ExampleKeywordCompletionProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionTask createTask(int queryType, JTextComponent jtc) {
        /**
         * We need to test whether the user pressed the keys applicable to the COMPLETION_QUERY_TYPE.
         */
        if (queryType != CompletionProvider.COMPLETION_QUERY_TYPE) return null;

        return new AsyncCompletionTask(new AsyncCompletionQuery(){


            @Override
            protected void query(CompletionResultSet crs, Document dcmnt, int caretOffset) {
                ExampleKeywords.find(crs, dcmnt, caretOffset).finish();
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getAutoQueryTypes(JTextComponent jtc, String string) {
        return 1;
    }
```

}

**ExampleKeywordCompletionItem**

```
public class ExampleKeywordCompletionItem implements CompletionItem {

    private String text;
    private static ImageIcon fieldIcon =
            new ImageIcon(ImageUtilities.loadImage("/org/netbeans/modules/plantumlnb/icon.png"));
    private static Color fieldColor = Color.decode("0x0000B2");
    private int caretOffset;
    private int dotOffset;

    ExampleKeywordCompletionItem(String keyword, int dotOffset, int caretOffset) {
        this.text = keyword;
        this.dotOffset = dotOffset;
        this.caretOffset = caretOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public void defaultAction(JTextComponent component) {
        try {
            StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) component.getDocument();
            //Here we remove the characters starting at the start offset
            //and ending at the point where the caret is currently found:
//            doc.remove(dotOffset, caretOffset - dotOffset);
            doc.insertString(dotOffset, text, null);
            //This statement will close the code completion box:
            Completion.get().hideAll();
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getPreferredWidth(Graphics graphics, Font font) {
        return CompletionUtilities.getPreferredWidth(text, null, graphics, font);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g, Font defaultFont, Color color, Color color1, int width, int height, boolean selected) {        
        CompletionUtilities.renderHtml(fieldIcon, text, null, g, defaultFont, 
                (selected ? Color.white : fieldColor), width, height, selected);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionTask createDocumentationTask() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionTask createToolTipTask() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean instantSubstitution(JTextComponent jtc) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSortPriority() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSortText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getInsertPrefix() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

**ExampleKeywords**

```
public class ExampleKeywords {

    public static final List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList(
            "as",
            "also",
            "autonumber",
            "title",
            "newpage",
            "box",
            "alt",
            "else",
            "opt",
            "loop",
            "par",
            "break",
            "critical",
            "note left",
            "note left of",
            "note left on link",
            "note right",
            "note right of",
            "note right on link",
            "note top",
            "note top of",
            "note top on link",
            "note bottom",
            "note bottom of",
            "note bottom on link",
            "note over",
            "note on",
            "end note",
            "ref over",
            "...",
            "group",
            "left",
            "right",
            "of",
            "on",
            "link",
            "over",
            "end",
            "activate",
            "deactivate",
            "destroy",
            "create",
            "footbox",
            "skinparam",
            "skin",
            "top",
            "bottom",
            "top to bottom direction",
            "package",
            "namespace",
            "page",
            "up",
            "down",
            "if",
            "endif",
            "partition",
            "footer",
            "header",
            "center",
            "rotate",
            "ref",
            "return",
            "is",
            "repeat",
            "start",
            "stop",
            "while",
            "endwhile",
            "fork",
            "again",
            /* TYPES */
            "actor",
            "participant",
            "usecase",
            "class",
            "interface",
            "abstract",
            "annotation",
            "enum",
            "component",
            "state",
            "object",
            /* PARTS */
            "artifact",
            "folder",
            "rect",
            "node",
            "frame",
            "cloud",
            "database",
            "storage",
            "agent",
            "boundary",
            "control",
            "entity",
            /* VISIBILITY */
            "show",
            "hide",
            "empty members"
    );


    public static List<String> find(String input) {
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            if (keyword.contains(input)) {
                allMatches.add(keyword);
            }
        }

        return allMatches;
    }

    public static CompletionResultSet find(CompletionResultSet crs, Document document, int caretOffset) {

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
                crs.addItem(new ExampleKeywordCompletionItem(keyword, 0, 0));
        }

        return crs;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

For completion: someone on the [Netbeans Forums](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic58036.html) has found a solution to your problem.

You need to pass the component to your `AsyncCompletionTask`.

```
@Override
public CompletionTask createTask(int queryType, JTextComponent jtc) {
    /**
     * We need to test whether the user pressed the keys applicable to the COMPLETION_QUERY_TYPE.
     */
    if (queryType != CompletionProvider.COMPLETION_QUERY_TYPE) return null;

    return new AsyncCompletionTask(new AsyncCompletionQuery(){

        @Override
        protected void query(CompletionResultSet crs, Document dcmnt, int caretOffset) {
            ExampleKeywords.find(crs, dcmnt, caretOffset).finish();
        }
    }, jtc); // <--
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, seems like that answer was posted way back in January, I never got the email. I will give this a try, hopefully PlantUML-NB can then have autocomplete.